# How to check and delete all existing db of sqflite in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

As I am new to flutter, I have created new DB whenever I have faced an issue, But now I need to remove other unused DB's. How can I check existing DB and delete them except currently using?

```
//final demoDb = 'demoDb1.db';
//final demoDb = 'demoDb2.db';
//final demoDb = 'demoDb3.db';
//final demoDb = 'demoDb4.db';
final demoDb = 'demoDb5.db'; //Currently using this one
```

```
createDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, demoDb);

    var database = await openDatabase(path,
        version: 1, onCreate: initDB, onUpgrade: onUpgrade);
    return database;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you recreate new DB each time you have an issue?
Can't you just use the same one with new tables/new records?

Comment: @dubace As I am new to flutter, Unknowingly I did it. But now I need to delete those.

Answer (score 1):

There is no flutter to way to list existing databases, you can however list files (a sqflite database is a file) in the directory you created them (I suggest using getDatabasesPath instead of getApplicationDocumentsDirectory).

You can then check if database exists ([databaseExists](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/databaseExists.html)) and delete it ([deleteDatabase](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/deleteDatabase.html)) assuming it is not open (in this case you must close it first)

Comment: So can't I see all existing DB's if I don't know the name of DB's I have created?

Comment: If you know the folder where they has been created, you can simply list the content of the folder (sqflite not involved here)

Comment: I tried many ways I am not able to achieve what you have mentioned above.